# How to convert list of dict to json in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of JSON and I want to convert then into single JSON, I tried with `json.dumps`, but that still gives a list of JSON as the result.

```
"response":[{"sent":46},{"drafts":2},{"completed":48},{"pending":1}]
```

I want it in the form of

```
"response":{"sent":46,"drafts":2,"completed":48,"pending":1}
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: So, you have a list if _dictionaries_ and you want to merge them into one _dictionary_?

Comment: assuming that all keys would be unique you can just use a dict comprehension like `{"response": {k: v for item in data['response'] for k, v in item.items()}}`

Comment: please can you guide, yes i want to convert list of dict to one dict

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, hey thanks got it

Comment: your output format should be 
`{'response': [{'sent': 46}, {'drafts': 2}, {'completed': 48}, {'pending': 1}]}`

Comment: You do NOT have "a list of json" - json is a text format, not a data type. What you have is dict whose "response" key is a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
from itertools import chain
r = {"response" :[{"sent":46},{"drafts":2},{"completed":48},{"pending":1}]}


r['response'] = dict(chain(*map(dict.items, r['response'])))
# same with:
# r['response'] = dict(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, r['response'])))
r
```

output:

```
{'response': {'sent': 46, 'drafts': 2, 'completed': 48, 'pending': 1}}
```

or you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
r['response'] = {k: v for d in r['response'] for k, v in d.items()}
```

output:

```
{'response': {'sent': 46, 'drafts': 2, 'completed': 48, 'pending': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
json_obj = {"response":[{"sent":46},{"drafts":2},{"completed":48},{"pending":1}]}
{k: {list(i.keys())[0]: list(i.values())[0] for i in v} for k, v in json_obj.items()}
```

that will output

```
{'response': {'sent': 46, 'drafts': 2, 'completed': 48, 'pending': 1}}
```